# Android allocation tracker shows many 300k+ newNonMovableArray allocations on ListView scroll

Tags: android, listview

I am using allocation tracker on my android application on a screen with a ListView.
I am getting a lot of this allocations :

7561    342732  byte[]  1   dalvik.system.VMRuntime newNonMovableArray

(342732 byte[] allocations)

Looks like one for each list item draw on screen. It is a custom draw cell with some bitmaps and so on. But none of them has 342kb.
This is the allocation trace :

https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c49ca2d021e575068e30

The only images I have are resources loaded on a image view. The resources are 32x32 so not something to cause a 300k allocation.

ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ImageView01); imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.delete)

As you can see it do not happens inside my app. So how can I have a idea of what is the problem ?

Comment: You should show us how you deal with bitmaps. In the allocation trace you provide, you can show that creating the bitmap is the cause of the allocations.

Comment: The only images I have are resources loaded on a image view. The resources are 32x32 so not something to cause a 300k allocation.  ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ImageView01);
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.delete);

Comment: Have you tried whithout setting the image resource in your adapter ? In this case you should not have this allocation issue. So the question is, how exactly did you set the image ? Can you show the whole code of the adapter ?